# Material UI: Access children nodes in <List> component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

Let's suppose I have a cart which is hidden and gets rendered only when I click on the cart icon in my shop. When the cart renders, inside of it I have a List component and inside of that I have three children (let's suppose these are items I added to the cart):

```
<List >
    <p>item1</p>
    <p>item2</p>
    <p>item3</p>
</List>
```

I need to know at any time how many items I have in the List so that I can show a little badge on the cart icon, with the number of items in the cart.
I read in the Material UI docs that List has a "children" prop which is an array of children components, but I'm pretty confused on how to access it and I was wondering if it keeps track of that array even when the cart is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ref for the list inside the constructor, and programmatically, compute the child length inside your render or where ever necessary.

```
constructor(props) {
   this.listboxRef = React.createRef();
}

<List ref={this.listboxRef}>
   <p>item1</p>
   <p>item2</p>
   <p>item3</p>
</List>

var cartCount = this.listboxRef.children().length;
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to React and I didn't go over class components, but I could accomplish the same thing using "useRef" hook, right?

Comment: Yea, Thats correct. In your case you won't have constructor. so you could do the same with useref inside the functional component.